# Calculate the length of curve

Tags: integration

The curve is the intersection of:
$$4x=(y+z)^2$$
$$4x^2+3y^2=3z^2$$

And the interval of curve length is from $O(0,0,0)$ to $M(x,y,z)$

The answer is $\sqrt2 z$

> My substitution is $u=y+z$ and $v=z-y$, then I put them into these two equations generating the relation of $u$ and $v$. However when I go down the track, trying to write the $dL$ to get the length, I found that the integral is **complex** to resolve. Did I go wrong or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inspection, one branch of the solution is $x=0$ and $y=-z$.  This is simply a line with with slope $-1$ in the $yz$-plane and, of course, the segment from the origin to a point $(0,-z,z)$ along this line has length $\sqrt{2}\,z$.

There is, however, another branch along which the problem could be harder.  The two branches are shown in the figure below.  My solution is for the diagonal line.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! And this is really a tricky skill. I search the wolfram for the $4x=(y+z)^2$ and it show **solution** is $x=0, y=-z$. I feel pretty strange what does the solution means here? I suppose x be any positive number.

Comment: @Sacheo You're welcome, though I wouldn't be so fast to accept this answer - I think it's missing something and someone else may spot it..  You can always upvote without accepting.